# c++, When I provide my shared library to user, which header files should be provided?

Tags: c++, shared-libraries

Suppose there are followings hierachi my shared library source.

MySharedLibraryData.h

```
#define DATA_TYPE (1)
```

MySharedLibrary.h

```
#include "MySharedLibraryData.h"
void FuncA();
```

MySharedLibrary.cpp

```
#include "MySharedLibrary.h"
#include "MySharedLibraryPrivate.h"
void FuncA(){ MySharedLibraryPrivate.FuncCore(DATA_TYPE); }
```

MySharedLibraryPrivate.h

```
void FuncCore(int dataType);
```

MySharedLibraryPrivate.cpp

```
void FuncCore(int dataType) { //do something using core logic; }
```

Case A) Do I need to provide libMySharedLibrary.so and MySharedLibrary.h, MySharedLibraryData.h to library user?

or

Case B) Do I need to provide libMySharedLibrary.so and MySharedLibrary.h, MySharedLibraryData.h and MySharedLibraryPrivate.h to library user?

which one is right?

I thought that I need to provide like Case A). is it wrong? If so, why?

Comment: You don't need to provide `MySharedLibraryPrivate.h`

Comment: Please do not answer in the comments section. Thanks.

Comment: @drescherjm, thanks :) but If I include "MySharedLibraryPrivate.h" in MySharedLibrary.h, Do I need to provide MySharedLibraryPrivate.h to user? right?

Comment: You should not include MySharedLibraryPrivate.h in MySharedLibrary.h it defeats the point of having a private header.

Comment: Yes, I know it. I just want to know whether I understand this situation.

Answer (score 1):

You should distribute what is needed to use the library and nothing else. Doing that will also help ensure a stronger division between private and public headers, in that you should create a test project that only has access to the public header and make sure that no dependencies on the private header are present.

Answer (score 0):

You should not provide `MySharedLibraryPrivate.h` and you should not have either of the headers in the public interface `MySharedLibraryData.h` or `MySharedLibrary.h` include the private header. This would defeat the purpose of having a private header.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I understood now.